# All rows getting update in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update a single row but found all rows are getting update.

Stuck since this morning. I don't want to use datatable.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUserProfile]
    @FirstName nvarchar(50),
    @MiddleName nvarchar(50),
    @LastName nvarchar(50),
    @Mobile nvarchar(50),
    @Aadhar nvarchar(50),   
    @PAN nvarchar(50),
    @Address text,
    @CityID int,
    @PinCode int,
    @StateID int,
    @CountryID int
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE tblUserProfiles  
    SET FirstName = @FirstName, 
        MiddleName = @MiddleName, 
        LastName = @LastName, 
        Mobile = @Mobile, Aadhar = @Aadhar, 
        PAN = @PAN, Address = @Address, 
        CityID = @CityID, PinCode = @PinCode, 
        StateID = @StateID, CountryID = @CountryID
    WHERE
        UserID = UserId 
END
```

`UserID` is triggered from another table to store it in this table. So I don't need to provide it again

Please give me a solution to me and error what I am missing

Comment: You have no `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` query...

Comment: Use the WHERE clause to update the particular Row.

Comment: Now you've got a where clause, asking if a field equals itself is always going to update everything.

Comment: my apologies....i forgot to mention where clause in the code here otherwise i am using it

Comment: UserId should have an argument, Ex. @UserId or some other varialble

Comment: actually UserID is retriving from another table through trigger so i don't need to put insert it again

Comment: If you do have the `where` clause in your code then please edit it here so we can try and help

Comment: So you forgot to mention it has a where clause but still chose not to post it.  UserID is from another table so you don't need to insert it again?  Well it is not working.

Comment: I updated my question but it was replaced by stack...sry  :(

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

> `WHERE UserID = UserID`

With this WHERE clause your query will update every row where the column value for UserID equals itself. This is every row. (Edit: Except, as pointed out below, if you have rows where UserID is NULL)

To have it update only one row, set the UserID to a specific value.

Example:
`WHERE UserID = '10'`

To have it update a set of rows, use a subquery or a WHERE IN like such:
`WHERE UserID IN (1,2,3,4,etc)`

**Reference pages on this site to help you:**
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp
http://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php

Comment: "where the column value for UserID equals itself. This is every row" - what about where UserID is null? ;)

Comment: Haha under a potentially false assumption! I assumed every user had an ID, probably should clarify that :)

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE` will update all rows that match a condition. When the condition is missing, SQL treats `UPDATE` as a request to update everything.

It looks like you are trying to update a record for user identified by its user id, so the query should be changed as follows:

```
UPDATE tblUserProfiles  
SET
    FirstName = @FirstName
,   MiddleName = @MiddleName
,   LastName = @LastName
,   Mobile = @Mobile
,   Aadhar = @Aadhar
,   PAN = @PAN
,   Address = @Address
,   CityID = @CityID
,   PinCode = @PinCode
,   StateID = @StateID
,   CountryID = @CountryID
WHERE UserID = @UserId -- add a WHERE clause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create proc [dbo].[spUserProfile]
@FirstName nvarchar(50),
@MiddleName nvarchar(50),
@LastName nvarchar(50),
@Mobile nvarchar(50),
@Aadhar nvarchar(50),   
@PAN nvarchar(50),
@Address text,
@CityID int,
@PinCode int,
@StateID int,
@CountryID int,
@UserId Int -- Added the missing argument

AS
Begin

    update tblUserProfiles  
    Set FirstName = @FirstName, MiddleName = @MiddleName, LastName = @LastName, 
        Mobile = @Mobile, Aadhar = @Aadhar, 
        PAN = @PAN, Address = @Address, CityID = @CityID,               
        PinCode = @PinCode, StateID = @StateID, CountryID = @CountryID,
        Where UserID = @UserId  -- Added the where clause

End
```

Comment: @rahul: Pl. be notified that I have added UserId as an argument and added the Where clause

Comment: You should include that information, as well as anything else you changed and why, in the body of your answer.  Not in the comments.

Comment: @Siyual: Thanks for the suggestion. I did that.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL syntax for `UPDATE` is as follows:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET column1 = value1, .... columnN = valueN
WHERE (condition)
```

You can find the same here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comparing the above syntax with your code, the extra comma (,) before your `where` clause begins, could be the reason why your code isn't encountering the where clause for what it is.

TRY:

```
UPDATE tblUserProfiles  
SET FirstName = @FirstName, 
    MiddleName = @MiddleName, 
    LastName = @LastName, 
    Mobile = @Mobile, Aadhar = @Aadhar, 
    PAN = @PAN, Address = @Address, CityID = @CityID,               
    PinCode = @PinCode, StateID = @StateID, CountryID = @CountryID
WHERE 
    UserID = UserId
```